# String Comparison __Lt__ operator python:

Tags: python, string, oop

I want to be able to compare 2 objects based on their attribute - Size.
Is the following correct? because it does not work

```
def __lt__(self, other): 
    if self.size == "small" and other.size == "big":
        return other.size > self.size
    if self.size == "small" and other.size == "medium":
        return other.size > self.size
    if self.size == "medium" and other.size == "big":
        return other.size > self.size
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean it does not work? What do you expect this code to do? Do you assume that the str type knows what the words big, medium, small mean as size comparisons, or did you intend to "tell" Python what they mean?

Comment: I  intend to "tell" Python what they mean. @mozway helped me, and now it works.Thank you both!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you need to return booleans :

```
def __lt__(self, other): 
    if self.size == "small" and other.size in ["big", "medium"]:
        return True
    if self.size == "medium" and other.size == "large":
        return True
    if ...
```

NB. you need to handle all possibilities

Comment: I would assume all other possibilities than the three in the question correspond to `False`.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi probably. Btw, a better implementation might be to map the names to numbers `{'small': 0, 'medium': 1, 'big': 3}` and forward the comparisons to int methods.